# How to understand firstVisibleItem and visibleItemCount in onScroll method?

Tags: android, gridview

I have gridview listing 9 items per page, and when user scrolls it should load 9 more. But i cannot set it properly, i am struggling with this code:

```
  public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem,
                                 int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {

             if((firstVisibleItem + visibleItemCount) == totalItemCount)
                   {
                 load_more();
                  }

            }
        });
```

I am not sure what to put on calculation line, so to give me 9 by 9 as user scrolls. I tried different calculations, but without success, sometimes it just loads automatically couple of times, sometimes infinite. How to accomplish what I need?

Answer (score 0):

There is a nice library which exactly does what you need.

https://github.com/shontauro/android-pulltorefresh-and-loadmore

**Sample**

```
((LoadMoreListView) getListView())
                .setOnLoadMoreListener(new OnLoadMoreListener() {
                    public void onLoadMore() {
                        // Do the work to load more items at the end of list here
                    }
                });
```

There are more options available in the library, you can try that as well.

For actually implementing for yourself, its quite difficult to do on onScroll. I too gave up and implemented through different procedure.

Comment: This is not an answer to the question.

Comment: @manabreak partly yes, partly no. I have suggested a better way. Which could have saved his time.

Comment: How can I implement this library, should i download whole code or just LoadMorelistView class from somewhere?

Comment: Do you know how to include a jar ? or module in Android Studio ?

Comment: yes, ok, ill try, but i would like to know exact answer to my question. But where is jar inside this repository?

Comment: there is no jar, you need to include library as module